# Accessing PostgreSQL with JDBC using LDAP authentication

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, ldap

Is the PostgreSQL feature of [authentication via LDAP](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-methods.html) available somehow when using the JDBC driver?
Looking at the [JDBC driver documentation](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/93/connect.html) it doesn't look like it's supported.
If not - any idea as to how to customize the driver to get it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LDAP authentication is server-side. To the client it's the same as `password` (clear-text password, so use SSL!) authentication.

In `src/backend/libpq/auth.c` the auth request function `void ClientAuthentication(Port *port)` calls `CheckLDAPAuth(port)` if LDAP auth is matched in `pg_hba.conf`.

This does a:

```
sendAuthRequest(port, AUTH_REQ_PASSWORD);
```

just like `password` does.

Any client driver that supports `password` auth supports `ldap`. [PgJDBC supports `password`](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/master/org/postgresql/core/v3/ConnectionFactoryImpl.java#L484).

The configuration options documented in the server docs are with reference to options set in `postgresql.conf` on the server side for authenticating users against the LDAP directory.

There is no change required to PgJDBC to use `ldap` auth.